# Difference between anacron command options - n and -f

Tags: server, anacron

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04. My query is regarding the anacron command options `-n` and `-f`.

Does `anacron -n` command run all the jobs (daily, weekly and monthly) scheduled in anacron or it only runs the jobs scheduled to run today?
I got the below output for this command `sudo anacron -n -d`:

```
Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-04-01
Normal exit (0 jobs run)
```

I got the below output for this command `sudo anacron -f -d`:

```
Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-04-01
Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Will run job `cron.weekly' in 10 min.
Will run job `cron.monthly' in 15 min.
```

Also when i combine both the `-n` and `-f` options, all the jobs started running without considering the delay.

Does anyone know how exactly both these options differ when using with anacron command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, anacron works in such a way that it will only execute any job if it hasn't already been executed within its given "timespan" (*hourly*, *daily*, *weekly* and *monthly*).

So if you run anacron for the first time in a week, it will run the tasks scheduled for *hourly*, *daily* and *weekly*. If you run it just afterwards, no tasks will be run. If you run it after an hour, only jobs scheduled for *hourly* will be run etc.

To keep track of this, anacron saves a timestamp for each job run. And only if the scheduled "timespan" exceeds the timestamp the job is run again.

Now the `-n` and `-f` options are described in the [anacron man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/anacron.8.html), and they do two distinctively different things.

- The `-f` option forces all jobs to be (re)run, *ignoring* the timestamps. This means if you run anacron several times just after each other with the `-f` option, it will rerun *all* jobs - including those that are scheduled to only run *daily*, *weekly* and *monthly*.
- The `-n` option tells anacron to run relevant jobs now, taking timestamps into account, but ignoring the delays set in `/etc/anacrontab`. The default delays (as evident from your output are):

  - `cron.daily` - 5 minutes
  - `cron.weekly` - 10 minutes
  - `cron.monthly` - 15 minutes

  In addition, the `-n` option also includes the `-s` option, so that the jobs are run in sequence (one after the other), as opposed to running the jobs for each "timespan" in parallel.

I think it's most clear to get an overview with a table:

| Options | Enforce timestamps | Enforce delays | Serial execution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *none* | Yes | Yes | No |
| `-s` | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| `-n` | Yes | No | Yes |
| `-f` | No | Yes | No |
| `-fs` | No | Yes | Yes |
| `-fn` | No | No | Yes |